# python program to find ave

Tags: python

> Continuously ask the user to enter numbers until the user enters a number that is greater than 100.  Then print the average value of the numbers before the last input.

Here is what i have so far

```
def main():
 sum = 0.0
 coum = 0
 num = input("Enter a Number")
 while num <= 100:
   sum = sum + num
   coum = count
   num = input("Enter a Number")
   ave = sum/count
 print ave
```

Comment: Maybe you should actually ... count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test this, you should think of cases which you can walk through your code and see if the requirements are satisfied.  Start with the simplest case in the beginning and work your way up to more complex cases.

Consider the case where the first number is greater than 100 at the start.  What lines get executed?

```
sum = 0.0
coum = 0
num = input("Enter a Number") # say: num = 200
while num <= 100:             # false, break out
print ave                     # oops, what is `ave`?
```

The calculation of `ave` should be done outside of the loop.  But even then, you still have to worry about the division by zero problem as `coum` would be zero.  I'll leave that for you to think about.  Let's assume that for the rest of this walkthrough, that calculation is moved out of the loop.

Next consider the case where the numbers are entered in this order: `100`, `200`.  What lines get executed this time?

```
sum = 0.0
coum = 0
num = input("Enter a Number") # num = 100
while num <= 100:             # true, let's keep going
sum = sum + num               # ok, 0.0 + 100 = 100.0
    # You probably would have seen a failure there,
    # depending on what version of Python you're using.
    # I will assume you're using Python 2.x.
coum = count                  # oops, what is `count`
```

There is no `count` variable here.  So you can't assign some unknown variable to another.  Though since we're trying to calculate the average of the numbers, a crucial number we need is the "count" of numbers that we are averaging.  The `coum` variable really should have been `count`.  At this point, you would want to be incrementing `count` by `1`.  Figure out how to do that.  Let's continue.

```
num = input("Enter a Number") # num = 200
while num <= 100:             # false, break out
ave = sum/count               # ave = 100.0 / 1 = 100.0
print ave
```

Try the same thing for the numbers: `100`, `50`, `200`.  What lines get executed then?  Figure that out and see if it still satisfies your requirements.  If it does, then great, try the next case.  If not, find out what's wrong and try to fix it.  If you're stumped, *ask* about it.  I hope you do a better job at that next time you ask a question here.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to python, Stackoverflow and, homework. The only problem I could see with your code is that you defined "coum", and didn't use it again, then asked for count, without it being defined prior.

What you need to do is:

- Create an incremental that counts how many number have been entered prior.
- Define one coum or count, and use that throughout.

You have these basically so far. Just make sure they're more defined.